# How can I use a second directory to stor shell scripts for a zsh shell?

Tags: terminal, sh, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I want to create a directory (for instance `~/scripts`) in which every file I store, could be executed globally:

**~/scripts/xy**

`echo hello world`

Just as if it was located under `/user/loca/bin`.

I have tried add this line to **.zshrc**:

`export PATH="~/scripts:$PATH"`

But still get:

`zsh: command not found: xy`

So I would like to get some help.

Thanks

EDIT: My **.zshrc** file looks like this and it worked:

```
export ZSH="$HOME/.oh-my-zsh"

ZSH_THEME="robbyrussell"

plugins=(git)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

export PATH="/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin:$PATH"
export PATH=$HOME/scripts:$PATH
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The double quotes prevent ~ from being expanded. Either put at least the `~/` outside the quotes, or express your home directory using `$HOME`.

BTW a perhaps more readable version is to use `path` instead of PATH:

```
path+=~/.scripts
```

Note that this appends your scripts directory at the end of the path instead at the beginning. This is probably the better choice anyway.